# Chunking with rule-based grammar in spacy

Tags: nlp, nltk, text-parsing, spacy

I have this simple example of chunking in nltk.

My data:

```
data = 'The little yellow dog will then walk to the Starbucks, where he will introduce them to Michael.'
```

...pre-processing ...

```
data_tok = nltk.word_tokenize(data) #tokenisation
data_pos = nltk.pos_tag(data_tok) #POS tagging
```

CHUNKING:

```
cfg_1 = "CUSTOMCHUNK: {<VB><.*>*?<NNP>}" #should return `walk to the Starbucks`, etc.
chunker = nltk.RegexpParser(cfg_1)
data_chunked = chunker.parse(data_pos)
```

This returns (among other stuff): `(CUSTOMCHUNK walk/VB to/TO the/DT Starbucks/NNP)`, so it did what I wanted it to do.

Now my question: I want to switch to spacy for my projects. How would I do this in spacy?

I come as far as to tag it (the coarser `.pos` method will do for me):

```
from spacy.en import English    
parser = English()
parsed_sent = parser(u'The little yellow dog will then walk to the Starbucks, where')

def print_coarse_pos(token):
  print(token, token.pos_)

for sentence in parsed_sent.sents:
  for token in sentence:
    print_coarse_pos(token)
```

... which returns the tags and tokens
`The  DET
little  ADJ
yellow  ADJ
dog  NOUN
will  VERB
then  ADV
walk  VERB
...`

How could I extract chunks with my own grammar?

Comment: Maybe, simply taking the pos tags as a string and creating the regex grammers we need and parsing could help solve the problem. To get the right word, we need the reverse mapping from POS to word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copied verbatim from https://github.com/spacy-io/spaCy/issues/342

There's a few ways to go about this. The closest functionality to that `RegexpParser` class is spaCy's `Matcher`. But for syntactic chunking, I would typically use the dependency parse. For instance, for NPs chunking you have the `doc.noun_chunks` iterator:

```
doc = nlp(text)
for np in doc.noun_chunks:
    print(np.text)
```

The basic way that this works is something like this:

```
for token in doc:
    if is_head_of_chunk(token)
        chunk_start = token.left_edge.i
        chunk_end = token.right_edge.i + 1
        yield doc[chunk_start : chunk_end]
```

You can define the hypothetical `is_head_of` function however you like. You can play around with the dependency parse visualizer to see the syntactic annotation scheme, and figure out what labels to use: http://spacy.io/demos/displacy

Comment: @ben_aaron I know you talked to Matthew Honnibal but I figured his reply should be posted here as well.

Comment: Same comment as in the quoted post, but I have the same question--how would an example is_head_of_chunk function defined?  I think the regular expression for a grammar chunk is the hardest part.